# Tasks aren't coming in the order I need them to

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm having a small issue with tasks.. below is a screenshot of a simple example of what I'm doing. I want the ThirdJob to show up first, then SecondJob, then FirstJob (or whatever order I'm doing it in).

[image]

I click the dropdown box, and it adds tasks to listbox1... then I press the button, and it executes those tasks based on a list(of task).

I have a 1000 MS delay on the ThirdJob, so of course, it comes in last. How do I make it so they come in the order I want them to, no matter how long it takes.

Current code I'm using to do this..

```
Dim tasklist As New List(Of Task)

Private Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

    For Each item In tasklist
        'item.RunSynchronously()
        item.Start()
    Next

    Await Task.WhenAll(tasklist.ToArray)

End Sub

Public Sub FirstJob()
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, DirectCast(Function() listbox2.Items.Add("FirstJob"), Action))
End Sub
Public Sub SecondJob()
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, DirectCast(Function() listbox2.Items.Add("SecondJob"), Action))
End Sub
Public Sub ThirdJob()
    Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, DirectCast(Function() listbox2.Items.Add("ThirdJob"), Action))
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)

    listbox1.Items.Add(cb1.SelectedItem)
    If cb1.SelectedItem.ToString = "FirstJob" Then
        tasklist.Add(New Task(Sub() FirstJob()))
    ElseIf cb1.SelectedItem.ToString = "SecondJob" Then
        tasklist.Add(New Task(Sub() SecondJob()))
    ElseIf cb1.SelectedItem.ToString = "ThirdJob" Then
        tasklist.Add(New Task(Sub() ThirdJob()))
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    cb1.Items.Add("FirstJob")
    cb1.Items.Add("SecondJob")
    cb1.Items.Add("ThirdJob")
End Sub
```

I'm sure the issue lies in how I'm doing my for loop though my array.

If I change

```
For Each item In tasklist
   item.Start()
Next

Await Task.WhenAll(tasklist.ToArray)
```

to

```
For Each item In tasklist
   item.Start()
   item.wait
Next
```

It goes in order, but freezes the UI, which I don't want.  Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like you need a background worker also if you want them in order you will need to order the `tasklist` if it is a List<T> then do a Sort on it.. have you even used the debugger to step thru the code as well as evaluate the `item` ..?

Comment: Here's a line from one of my favourite songs that might help - "take me down to concurrency city where green pretty is grass the girls the and are".

Comment: @Enigmativity Clever +1

Comment: @TonyW: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @StephenCleary : It seems to me he wants to get the output from the tasks in a sequential order.

Comment: @visual Vincent Correct I'm trying to get them in sequential order

Comment: @TonyW: You want to run them all at the same time, and just order the outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a custom method and utilizing the `Task.ContinueWith()` method to start the tasks after each other?

```
Public Class TaskHelper
    Public Shared Function RunAllSequential(ByVal Tasks() As Task) As Task
        For i = 0 To Tasks.Length - 2 'Using -2 since the last task don't need to start another one.
            Dim j As Integer = i
            Tasks(i).ContinueWith(Sub() Tasks(j + 1).Start())
        Next

        Tasks(0).Start() 'Start the first task.

        Return Task.WhenAll(Tasks)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This will run the specified tasks after each other. When the first one is done the second one will be started, and so on.

**Example use:**

```
Await TaskHelper.RunAllSequential(tasklist.ToArray())
```

Comment: Please note that I wrote this from my phone; I have not yet tested it. So if you experience any problems please tell me.

Comment: I will check this as soon as I'm home, thank you. It might be a list of 2 or 3, or maybe 20. I assume I'll just need to get the list length and take away everything but the initial item, so it's done first and everything beyond that is continue with.

Comment: @TonyW : No, you don't need to take away anything. Just convert the list to an array like you did above. My code will: **1)** Set each tasks' (except for the last one) `ContinueWith()` to start the next task. **2)** Start the first task only. **3)** Call `Task.WhenAll()` with the array as the parameter and return the resulting task. -- You should literally just be able to copy-paste my class and in your code change `Await Task.WhenAll(tasklist.ToArray)` to `Await TaskHelper.RunAllSequential(tasklist.ToArray())`.

Comment: It only runs the first task in the list, nothing else fires.

Comment: I had to change this to get it to work..

`Dim j = i
Tasks(i).ContinueWith(Sub() Tasks(j + 1).Start())`

Comment: I get `Start may not be called on a task that has completed.` error if I run this twice, because I will have 200+ users i'm running this list(of task) on. Any clue on how to fix it?

Comment: @TonyW It is not possible to run a Task multiple times. So if you want to run this method twice, you have to create *new* task objects which are provided via parameter `Tasks()`. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/14/10256832.aspx) article (Question 2) for more information about Tasks

Comment: @TonyW : Oh, you're right. Due to that `i` is in the loop it constantly changes so you must declare a new variable. Will update my answer with that. Nice job pinpointing it. :)

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate the downvote, or is it still the hater who's been following me for a couple of months?

Comment: Not I, you've been nothing but helpful.

Comment: @TonyW : Thank you :). Didn't think it was you either because then it would be strange that you marked it as accepted.

Comment: @AlexB. I've read through, and I guess I still just don't understand how I would do that. Thanks

Comment: @VisualVincent I do not downote any answers (except it provides harmful code)

Comment: @AlexB. : I don't think it was either of you two. Though there's been a hater following me on SO, and it feels like this was a downvote of his or hers kind.

Comment: @VisualVincent That´s kinda sad. Will you update your answer regarding task creation?

Comment: @AlexB. : You mean update with code to be able to re-run the list of tasks? I might, but I'll have to look into it a bit more first. I am also going somewhere this weekend so it might take a few days before I'm able to, too.